# How can I update the label everytime in loop with tkinter configure. Below code only displaying the final loop string

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import time

win = Tk()
def call():
    for i in range(5, 0, -1):
        time.sleep(1)
        l1.configure(text = str(i) + " seconds left")

l1 = Label(win, text = "Timer")
l1.pack()

b1 = Button(win, text = "Click", command = call)
b1.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

This code is waiting for the 4 seconds and giving the final loop value only

Comment: Avoid using `sleep` with tkinter, look into `after` method

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a problem with tkinter as we are using the time module I guess, the way I got around is by changing the name of the window here is the code, also you may want to use f strings:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

win = Tk()
win.geometry('300x400')

def call():
    for i in range(5, 0, -1):
        i -= 1
        time.sleep(1)
        win.title(f'{i} seconds left')

l1 = Label(win, text = "Timer")
l1.pack()

b1 = Button(win, text = "Click", command = call)
b1.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: This will freeze the GUI every 1 second till the loop is done, so this does not answer the question

Comment: Thanks, but I need to change the label (l1) value. The above code changing the title value..

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria @Dodu after searching for long time I came to know that the window did not updating. So, we need to use `win.update()`

Comment: Forcing an event loop each second is also not a good idea

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria   Is there any other method instead of update.. ?

Comment: @Siva Reddy thanks for telling me that I could possibly use that

Comment: Check the other answer @SivaReddy

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
# import time

win = Tk()
def call():
    for i in range(5, 0, -1):
        win.update()                     # gets updated everytime
        l1.configure(text = str(i) + " seconds left")
        win.after(1000)                  # sleep for a second
   
l1 = Label(win, text = "Timer")
l1.pack()

b1 = Button(win, text = "Click", command = call)
b1.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

This code worked..

Answer (score 0):

Using `time.sleep()` in tkinter application is not recommended.  Use `.after()` instead:

```py
def call(i=5):
    l1.configure(text=f"{i} seconds left")
    if i > 0:
        l1.after(1000, call, i-1)
```